# Fields and sigma fields generated by finite sets

Tags: measure-theory, proof-verification

Working on number 1.12 in Resnick's "The Probability Path"

Let $\Omega = \{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ and $\mathbb{C} = \{\{2,4\},\{6\}\}$. What is the field generated by $\mathbb{C}$ and what is the $\sigma$-field?

I know that a field is a non empty class of subsets of $\Omega$ closed under finite union, complementation, and contains $\Omega$ and a sigma field is similar save closed under countable union and complementation.

I'm getting hung up on the "field generated by $\mathbb{C}$ part." I know that this field, $\sigma(\mathbb{C}) \subset \mathbb{C}$, but I'm having difficulty deducing an answer from this broad statement. My initial thought is that $\sigma(\mathbb{C}) = \mathbb{P}(\Omega) \cup \emptyset$

Where $\mathbb{P}(\Omega)$ is the power set of $\Omega$.

Edit: Should be $\mathbb{C} \subset \sigma(\mathbb{C})$ and $\sigma(\mathbb{C}) = P(\Omega) \cup \{ \emptyset \}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, I think you mean $\mathbb{P}(\Omega) \cup \{\emptyset\}$ in your last line, as $\mathbb{P}(\Omega) \cup \emptyset = \mathbb{P}(\Omega)$.  But that is just a minor nitpick.

With regard to your question, recall that $\sigma(\mathbb{C})$ is the smallest $\sigma$-field that contains $\mathbb{C}$ (note that $\sigma(\mathbb{C}) \supseteq \mathbb{C}$, and not the other way around, as you wrote).  Thus it has to contain all of the sets of $\mathbb{C}$, and just enough extra sets to ensure that it is closed under complements and unions, and includes all of $\Omega$.

This is a relatively small example, so you should be able to brute force it.  Starting with $\mathbb{C}$, you need to throw in other sets so that you get the properties that you want (closure under unions, complements, etc).  So you might proceed as follows:

1. You know that $\mathbb{C}$ has to be in $\sigma(\mathbb{C})$, so start with that.  So far, we have $\{ \{2,4\}, \{6\} \}$.
2. You require $\Omega \in \sigma(\mathbb{C})$, so throw that in: $\{ \{2,4\}, \{6\}, \Omega \}$.
3. Now, $\sigma(\mathbb{C})$ has to be closed under complements, so include the complements of the three sets that are in there:  $\{ \{2,4\}, \{1,3,5,6\}, \{6\}, \{1,2,3,4,5\}, \Omega, \emptyset \}$.
4. Next, we need to make sure that we have closure under unions, which means that we need to throw in unions of any sets.  So... $\{2,4\} \cup \{1,3,5,6\}$ is already in the collection; $\{2,4\} \cup \{6\} = \{2,4,6\}$, and $\{1,3,5\} \cup \{6\} = \{1,3,5,6\}$ is already in the collection.  No other pairwise unions give us anything new, nor do unions including more sets.  So now we have the collection $\{ \{2,4\}, \{1,3,5,6\}, \{6\}, \{1,2,3,4,5\}, \Omega, \emptyset, \{2,4,6\} \}$.
5. We introduced a new set, so we ned to include its complement.  Throwing that in, we get $\{ \{2,4\}, \{1,3,5,6\}, \{6\}, \{1,2,3,4,5\}, \Omega, \emptyset, \{2,4,6\}, \{1,3,5\} \}$.
6. Again, check all unions.  In this case, taking the union of the new set $\{1,3,5\}$ with any other set in our collection gives us nothing new.  Therefore the collection in step 5 is closed under unions.  Since step 5 ensured that it was closed under complements as well, and step 2 included the entire space, this collection gets the job done.

Therefore
$$ \sigma(\mathbb{C})
= \{ \emptyset, \{6\}, \{2,4\}, \{1,3,5\}, \{2,4,5\}, \{1,3,5,6\}, \{1,2,3,4,5\}, \Omega \} $$
Note that this is not the powerset of $\Omega$, as (for example) none of the singleton sets other than $\{6\}$ are included.

Comment: Fantastic answer - thanks for correcting my mis-statements and for identifying where/why I was wrong. This has greatly improved my understanding of sigma fields

Answer (score 1):

If $\mathcal A=\{A_1,\dots,A_n\}\subseteq\wp(\Omega)$ and moreover the sets are disjoint and cover $\mathcal A$, then it is not so difficult to find the field generated by the collection. Just take the collection of unions of sets and you can find easily that this collection is closed under finite union and complementation.

---

Starting with $\mathcal A=\{A_1,\dots,A_n\}\subseteq\wp(\Omega)$ then there are at most $2^n$ distinct sets of the form $B_1\cap\cdots\cap B_n$ where $B_i\in\{A_i,A_i^c\}$ for $i=1,\dots,n$.

In your example we have $\mathcal A=\{\{2,4\},\{6\}\}$ and $\mathcal B=\{\varnothing,\{2,4\},\{6\},\{1,3,5\}\}$

It is evident that the elements of $\mathcal B$ belong to the field generated by $\mathcal A$.

Also the sets in $\mathcal B$ form a "pseudo-partition" of $\Omega$ in the sense they cover $\Omega$ and are mutually disjoint. So actually we landed now in the situation described above.

The sets that can be written as a union of these sets together form the field generated by $\mathcal A$.

In your example that results in:$$\{\varnothing,\{2,4\},\{6\},\{1,3,5\},\{2,4,6\},\{1,2,3,4,5\},\{1,3,5,6\},\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}\}$$